# SQL to calculate a %

Tags: sql

I have the following **2 columns**:

1) transaction_amount = **$48.15**

2) merchant_commission = **10%**

And I need to calculate the 2 columns below, which is a 60/40 split of the 10% commission above (6% and 4%).

Currently, I do the following manual calculations:

3) commission_split 1 = **0.04** x 48.15 (which is the transaction_amount above)

4) commission_split 2 = **0.06** x 48.15 (which is the transaction_amount above)

I'm looking for the query that makes this calculation automatically for each of the commission splits.

Answer (score 2):

do the following:

```
Select
    0.04 x transaction_amount as commission_split1,
    0.06 x transaction_amount as commission_split2
From
    Tablename;
```